# Were Asian actors cast for native Jedha citizens for a reason?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, actors

In *Rogue One*, Jyn and Cassian visit Jedha City which is packed with crowd. There were pilgrims and other spacefarers from all over the galaxy, but the humans, who appeared to be native citizens to the city, were mostly portrayed by Asian people. And I don't mean only Chirrut and Baze, but also the crying girl, and her mother, and the old ladies, and a number of more.

[image]

Did this casting have a special meaning? The [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159175/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-rogue-ones-chirrut-and-baze-is-a-reference-to) pointed out  the connections between *Rogue One* and *The Hidden Fortress*, so maybe this is somehow related to that.

Comment: You have different colors of Ewok. Why not Space-Chinese?

http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/b7/Ewoks-endor.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20071018160826

Comment: Chirrut looks like a samurai, it would be difficult to imagine a non-asian in this role

Comment: @TimSparrow Tom Cruise? Though that has complications of its own.

Comment: Interestingly, the Holy City is based on real life holy cities such as Jerusalem and Mecca, and has many middle-eastern influences, but the inhabitants seems to be very much far-eastern. I assume this is partly because peoples like the Chinese are generally seen to be more spiritual, which fits with the theme of of Jedha being essentially the home of The Force, and partly because given the current public opinion in the Western World, it probably didn't seem a good idea to try and market a city full of Muslims to an American audience.

Comment: Because Star Wars is super unpopular in China and this is Disney's attempt to fix that. Google it :).

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert in Star Wars lore by any means, but there are circumstances where planets are based on certain sections of Earth, most notably Yavin 4 which is based on Guatemala. This is the planet Poe is said to be from in TFA as the actor who plays him is from Guatemala and wished to be from there. 
It is entirely possible that Jedha is based upon some Asian country, hence the choice in actors, although where I don't know. Also the order Chirrut is part of,and the fighting style he has,seems to have echos of monk like orders (think Asian based religions such as Buhddism) and martial arts, which also originate in Asia. Therefore, it makes sense to have an Asian style planet.
However this is just speculation, given the facts of the movies and a bit of logical thinking. I could be wrong so as for clarification with some one who is better acquianted with the universe!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFF:SE. I know that you're a new user, and don't have enough rep to leave a comment, but this is a comment, not an answer, so it's likely to be moved / closed. You should try to post a well-researched answer to a question or think of a really good question to ask to get some upvotes and increase your rep. You only need 50 rep to be able to leave a comment.

Comment: Welcome to the site =) You're right there is a lot of speculation here and some unsourced claims. But that's alright this is your first post, if you were to add some references to interviews and things to back some of the claims up, for instance that Yavin 4 is based from Guatemala and that's why Poe is from there, and generally try and make your answer more concrete and fact-based, you could have a decent answer =) And please don't be put off by these comments, we're a Q&A site here with fairly high standards, rather than a forum for example, so we like to have evidence

Comment: And it's important to explain this kind of thing to new users, but it's never meant in a bad way, but to help you get used to the site and get the most out of it - and give the most to it. So welcome =)